# How can I center a background image's width?

Tags: html, css

It seems to me no matter what I try I cannot get complete control over both the width and height of a background image.

Why is my background-position: center not working?

```css
.full-page-container {      background:url(https://files.pitchbook.com/website/images/content/Midwest.png) center no-repeat;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 80%;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-page-container">
  <div class="heading-wrapper">
    <h1 id="title">Heading Title</h1>
    <p id="description">Header description</p>
  </div>

  <div class="form-wrapper">
    <form id="survey-form">
      <div class="name-wrapper">
        <label for="name" id="name-label">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="First Name" required>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: background-size might be what you look for ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: well if you define a fixed height, then the width can be fixed aswell without breakign the aspect ratio. Contain will keep the aspect ration and creat white space while cover will also keep the aspect ratio but be cropped. Aletrnativly youc an use fill, but the aspect ration will be messed up and the image streched/squashed.

Comment: Object-fit:fill also does not fill the height and width as desired.

Comment: try cover, but i hardly believe that you learned about background-size and every type use in a few minutes ... , why do you need 100vh at first if content cuts it out ? Uou should clarify the question with an example than describe well your issue. you can use images from https://picsum.photos/images if you want to kee discret about your own ;)

Comment: I turned your code into a snippet, you may update as you wish to demonstrate your issue and eventually a screenshot of the expected result.

Comment: Thank you, will insert an image so you can see the issue.

Comment: I am trying to center the image while keeping its height 100vh and width 80%

Comment: Any thoughts why I am having issues centering it now? I changed to pixels and got some control over height and width, I tried background-position:center; And set center on background-size;

Answer (score 2):

You can change the size by using [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size). You can actually set 2 values for it, like this:

```
background-size: x y;
```

where x is the width and y is the height.

So something like this:

```css
.full-page-container{
   background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1497581175344-8a5f1a0142a5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=658&q=80");
   background-size: 80% 100vh;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center;
   height: 100vh;
   width:80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-page-container"></div>
```

or this

```css
.full-page-container{
   background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1497581175344-8a5f1a0142a5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=658&q=80");
   background-size: 100% 100%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center;
   height: 100vh;
   width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-page-container"></div>
```

Comment: Why do you have to repeat using the height and width after putting it in the background size?

Comment: This lets me use 100vh but is still oddly affecting the width.

Comment: I know it seems really straightforward but in practice you get different results

Comment: The `width` and `height` are for the element (not the background). thanks for your comment!

Comment: If you want, you can set the background-size to 100% 100% and control it with the width, if that's what your looking for.

Comment: More questions! what is the element you are referring to? And using 100% 100%, then going in to change the width only kind of works, as above. It changes the width but the height is only 100% of the content (same when 100vh is used)

Comment: First question - I am referring to just an ordinary div, noting too special here.

Comment: The other strange thing is, when I try the above code as you wrote above, it does not let me center the image in the middle of the page. So in that case the height is correct, but the width will not center

Comment: @Elizabeth I have added `background-position: center`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223650/discussion-between-elizabeth-and-corn-on-the-cob).

Answer (score 1):

You can try background-size css property with width and height values specified. See [Resizing background images with background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Backgrounds_and_Borders/Resizing_background_images)

Comment: That works sort of. It still does not let me use 100vh as a height. It cuts it short at the height of the content.

Comment: Can you explain to me a bit more what are you trying to achieve?